# Are there any SDKs to control Sphero Mini?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, sphero-api, sphero

Recently I got [Sphero Mini](https://www.sphero.com/sphero-mini), and am looking for SDKs/Libraries to control it via scripts. (I don't have any program language preference.) I looked into [developer documents](https://developer.gosphero.com/) and [Orbotix's github](https://github.com/orbotix), but looks like all existing libraries does not support Sphero Mini. Does anyone know any?

Answer (score 3):

Update:  There is a new library being developed that looks quite promising:

https://github.com/igbopie/spherov2.js

Other than that and as far as I know there are currently no supported SDK's for the sphero mini other than the orbotix edu app.  I've opened up a ticket on github for the Javascript SDK:

https://github.com/orbotix/sphero.js/issues/95

If you've since found any information it would be great if you could post an update here.

Comment: Nice! Yes, I am working on that SDK. I would love to see someone using it and creating issues. I don't mind collaboration :)